# Using oldstylenums with siunitx. Or making it the default style in document

Tags: oldstylenums

I am attempting to add use siunitx and want all my numbers to be in the oldstyle. However, I am unable to compile it correctly.
Something like \SI{\oldstylenums{23}}{\milli\Molar} throws errors at me. Is there some way of making all numbers (if possible, including bibliography, but excluding dois) to have oldstylenums format?
I am using TexMaker (pdfLaTeX).

My current preamble is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
%Page Setting
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}     %For adding Figures
\usepackage{float}        %For removing figure borders
\usepackage{tabularx}      %For making tables
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}     %For multirow tables
\usepackage{csquotes}     %For the ability to use single or double inverted commas
\usepackage{booktabs}      % For \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Generates table from .csv
\usepackage{longtable}     %Allows multi-page tables
\usepackage{rotating}      %Allows for single page landscape using \sidewaystable{}
\usepackage{pdflscape}     %Allows for landscape
\usepackage{multirow}      %Allows for merging across rows
\usepackage{tablefootnote} 
\usepackage{url}               %Allows for writing urls correctly.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{lineno}        %For adding line numbers
\usepackage{threeparttable} %For a more structured tables
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage[alsoload=synchem]{siunitx}          %For the ability to write SI units
\sisetup{input-uncertainty-signs=\pm, 
        separate-uncertainty=true}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\bfseries\normalsize}

\usepackage[toc,numberline]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage[%backend=biber, 
style=numeric, 
natbib=true,
url=false,
giveninits=true, 
maxbibnames=200, 
sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

%To get SIAM-like format in references
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\newbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{publisher}}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{institution}}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{\usebibmacro{pubinstorg+location+date}{organization}}


% print url if no doi
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    \printfield{doi}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}{%
        \usebibmacro{eprint}%
    }{}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iffieldundef{doi}{%
        \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}%
        {}%
    }
```

Comment: TeXmaker is a "front end"; as such, it has no influence on the numeral style that's employed in the document. The style of numerals -- lining or oldstyle -- is a font property. Which font family/ does your document employ? Which TeX engine is in use: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else?

Comment: I am using pdfLaTeX